# Are there any rules for DNS root zone file changes?

Tags: dns

Are there any rules when TLD's owner try to change DNS root zone file? For example, you cannot change more than half of the authoritative servers for a top-level domain at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in IANA's [Root Zone Management](https://www.iana.org/domains/root), in particular the [Change requests → Procedures and guides](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/help) section.

It lists the [Technical requirements](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements) that *any* change must conform to, and while the amount of changes isn't mentioned as a *technical* requirement, it does mention that changes which actually attempt to switch nameservers to a different operator would indeed be handled by a completely different "re-delegations" procedure:

> If the request is deemed to represent a substantial change of control of the TLD, it is considered a redelegation request, and must be assessed according to the criteria of that process

Comment: I know the change rule on iana website, above are what is acceptable change. But what I want to learn is that how we can  realize when it changes unacceptablely(maybe maliciously tampered？).

Comment: How would an "unacceptable" change go through the procedures in the first place? The TLD operators don't have direct access to the zone file; they can only _ask IANA_ to perform changes.

Comment: Suppose IANA is not credible.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking about. If you're saying that IANA's rules are irrelevant, then *whose* rules do you want to know about?

Comment: Sorry for my terrible expression. What I want to learn is that how can we realize the zone file maliciously tampered by iana or somebody? Because the data is updated according to the rules published by iana. So I am trying to find whether the zone file is maliciously tampered by using these rules. If the zone file violates these rules, we should think about its correctness? And now I am looking for these rules.

Comment: Well, I already linked to the rules published by IANA, and you said those were irrelevant.

Comment: I have read the rules published by IANA and I don't think that it is irrelevant but there is just a little info which is not enough by reading these rules. So I want to ask for more info from any other organization.

Comment: "So I want to ask for more info from any other organization."There are no other organization. IANA is the sole steward of the root zone.It is now a service of PTI, Public Technical Identifiers, which is an affiliate of ICANN.In the past, IANA was  still tied somehow to US DoD that could have changed (and did probably) decisions. But ICANN gained few years ago independence from US government (it is still a US non-profit so bound by US rules anyway). IANA has its own internal technical rules, but there is also RFC6168 and RFC2870 for root nameservers but TLD ones can share some of same problems.